# Pull rows from a Google Sheet, and place them into an email (365)

Tags: automation, workflow, make.com

im stuck with an automation workflow on Make.com

I'm trying to create a flow that starts with Google Forms, once a form has been submitted, it will automatically add a new row in Sheets, and then send them a confirmation email.

However, I want to send myself an email when the first 3 forms are created, with the details that they have entered in the form. As of right now, i have everything set up correctly except the final email. I can't figure out how to pull the 3 rows of data from Sheets. I can only pull the most recent row.

Does anyone have any experience with this?

Thanks!

Tried using different parameters but couldn't find anything that worked

Answer (score 0):

If you know the empty row is always going to be in a expected range of rows you can use "Google Sheets" -> "Get Range Values", aggregate them into a single array and then get slice of only that last 3 array items.

For example with the following sheet I want to get that last 3 rows and send them as as single text to my Slack channel.

[image]

This is my setup:

[image]

[image]

I'm only selecting row range A1:A10.

The only complicated module is the "Last3" where I do the array transformation (`0` is raw variable name):

[image]

Then sending the Slack message is pretty simple:

[image]
[image]

The whole scenario consumed only 5 operations.